# Can't seem to select root tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use `select` to select tags with BeautifulSoup, but it seems that BeautifulSoup will select a root tag if it's part of a `BeautifulSoup` object, but not if it's just in a `tag` object.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup()
>>> a = soup.new_tag("a")
>>> a = a.wrap(soup.new_tag("b"))
>>> soup.append(a)
>>> soup
<b><a></a></b>
>>> a
<b><a></a></b>
>>> soup.select("b")
[<b><a></a></b>]
>>> a.select("b")
[]
>>> a.select("a")
[<a></a>]
```

Short of creating a new `BeautifulSoup` object that consists only of `a`, is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

At first, beautify your string:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> a='<b><a></a></b>'
>>> a=BeautifulSoup(a)
>>> a
<html><body><b><a></a></b></body></html>
>>> a.select("b")
[<b><a></a></b>]
>>> a.select("a")
[<a></a>]
>>>
```

That's the way BeautifulSoup works!

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Why can't I select the root element on a `tag` that's not part of a `BeautifulSoup` object?